# Merge array of observable arrays into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have following Observable that I need to flatten into a single observable array:

```
Observable<Observable<any[]>[]> values;
```

where the inner arrays look like this for example:

```
[
  {id: 0, name: 'a'}, 
  {id: 1, name: 'b'}
], 
[
  {id: 0, name: 'a'}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'c'}
], 
[
  {id: 1, name: 'b'}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'd'}
]
```

This should be converted to `Observable<any[]>`
where the array looks like this:

```
[
  {id: 0, name: 'a'},
  {id: 1, name: 'b'},
  {id: 2, name: 'c'},
  {id: 3, name: 'd'}
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a `forkJoin`:

```
values.pipe(
    switchMap((values) => forkJoin(values)),
    map((result) => Array.from(new Set(arr.flat()))
).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

This solution only works under **1 condition**:

All Observables inside the array must trigger **exactly once** and resolve, otherwiese the forkJoin won't work. The outer Observable can trigger as much times as you want. If the inner Observables trigger continuously, you might want to use `combineLatest` with `mergeAll`, but the output will only be one element at a time and not all together.

Answer (score 0):

Make a use of ***`Lodash JavaScript Library`*** in addition to **`new Set()`** .
There are 3 methods to flatten an array

**`flatten`** , **`flattenDeep`** and **`flattenDepth`**

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript,you can use **flat** to resolve this problem or you can use basic loop to deal with it
and tip: you must consider the compatibility of this method